# Counting number of values in an array larger than a selected field in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

For my example, I have a very simple array [1,2,3,4,5] and I want to find the number of items in this array that are greater than or equal to 3. If I use countif(array,">=3") i get an output of 3, obviously. But I want to be able to reference a cell, lets say A7. Assuming A7 = 3 if I then use =COUNTIF(A1:A5,">=A7") it would simply return 0.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the letter and even if I remove the "" marks it still doesn't work. I must be overlooking something simple right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include the cell reference in quotes, instead this should work:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A5,">="&A7)`